# C# SqlDataReader reads only 1 row

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I'm trying to read data from database to store in arrays, but `SqlDataReader` only reads 1 row which is either the last or the first depending if I use `ORDER BY DESC` or `ASC` which seems to bug me.

Code:

```
private void chkAdr()
{
    string connStr = "Data Source=MARINCHI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=login1;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand getAdr = new SqlCommand("SELECT adress, floor,city, state, country, zipcode FROM userAdress where userID = @userID", conn);

    SqlParameter parUserID = new SqlParameter("@userID", Login.id);
    getAdr.Parameters.Add(parUserID);

    getAdr.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataReader dr = getAdr.ExecuteReader();

    string[] adress = new string[100];
    string[] floor = new string[100]; 
    string[] city = new string[100]; 
    string[] state = new string[100]; 
    string[] country = new string[100]; 
    string[] zipcode = new string[100]; 

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int count = dr.FieldCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            adress[i] = dr["adress"].ToString();
            floor[i] = dr["floor"].ToString();
            city[i] = dr["city"].ToString();
            state[i] = dr["state"].ToString();
            country[i] = dr["country"].ToString();
            zipcode[i] = dr["zipcode"].ToString();
        }

        // test to see, what values I get, no matter what adress[i] for I any number, always get the last data from my table in sql...
        textBox5.Text = adress[0];
        textBox6.Text = floor[0];
        textBox7.Text = city[0];
        textBox8.Text = state[1];
        textBox9.Text = country[1];
        textBox10.Text = zipcode[1];
    }

    dr.Close();
}
```

I tried `dr.HasRows` but it didn't really work for me, and I searched on google and tried all combinations but nothing seems to work, I can't get it to work with reading from begging to last row..

This should be a component of my code to retrieve adress from database if a user added his address before, if it ends up true, its gonna be added to combobox as option "Saved address 1" and when u click on it, it should display it in textboxes. Same if there are 2 addresses, both should be added.

As I said my problem is I can't read all addresses the user has added as the `SqlDataReader` reads only either last row or first row only.. If anyone has a idea on how I can do this, please help! thanks!

Comment: Why are you executing ExecuteNonQuery and then ExecuteReader?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery cuz im using parameters used in execution of sql command, and execute reader to read data from db and to be able to store em in array.

Comment: You don't need to call  getAdr.ExecuteNonQuery(), ExecuteReader is enough

Comment: Ok, i will remove it, thanks for that, but still doesnt help me with my real problem of why it reads only one row, either last or first:(

Comment: IMHO your code should work, could you doble check your data? test your query in SSMS.

Comment: Checked, everything seems to be good. Except this, maybe I should use a different approach? Is there a command to move thro rows?

Comment: `while (dr.Read())` does that job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You looping is not correct, you should read like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (dr.Read())
{            
    adress[i] = dr["adress"].ToString();
    floor[i] = dr["floor"].ToString();
    city[i] = dr["city"].ToString();
    state[i] = dr["state"].ToString();
    country[i] = dr["country"].ToString();
    zipcode[i] = dr["zipcode"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Noticed that, but still doesnt fix problem, I did it with for loop with i < 3 instead of i < count, cuz i have 3 rows of adresses in my DB table. :(

Comment: You have for loop in the while loop, so you write the same row three times, rewriting everything you had there. You end up with the last row three times.

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is now. Let me try that.